# What is the algorithm name of the following code?

Tags: java, android, tic-tac-toe

this is a code for android tic tac toe game. but i can't understand what algorithm are they using? can anyone tell which algorithm is being used here?

```
package va.indiedevelopment.tictactoe;

import java.util.Random;

public class TicTacToeGame {

    private char mBoard[];
    private final static int BOARD_SIZE = 9;

    public static final char HUMAN_PLAYER = 'X';
    public static final char ANDROID_PLAYER = '0';
    public static final char EMPTY_SPACE = ' ';

    private Random mRand;

    public static int getBOARD_SIZE() {
        return BOARD_SIZE;
    }

    public TicTacToeGame(){

        mBoard = new char[BOARD_SIZE];

        for (int i = 0; i < BOARD_SIZE; i++)
            mBoard[i] = EMPTY_SPACE;

        mRand = new Random();
    }

    public void clearBoard()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < BOARD_SIZE; i++)
        {
            mBoard[i] = EMPTY_SPACE;
        }
    }

    public void setMove(char player, int location)
    {
        mBoard[location] = player;
    }

    public int getComputerMove()
    {
        int move;

        for (int i = 0; i < getBOARD_SIZE(); i++)
        {
            if (mBoard[i] != HUMAN_PLAYER && mBoard[i] != ANDROID_PLAYER)
            {
                char curr = mBoard[i];
                mBoard[i] = ANDROID_PLAYER;
                if (checkForWinner() == 3)
                {
                    setMove(ANDROID_PLAYER, i);
                    return i;
                }
                else
                    mBoard[i] = curr;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < getBOARD_SIZE(); i++)
        {
            if (mBoard[i] != HUMAN_PLAYER && mBoard[i] != ANDROID_PLAYER)
            {
                char curr = mBoard[i];
                mBoard[i] = HUMAN_PLAYER;
                if (checkForWinner() == 2)
                {
                    setMove(ANDROID_PLAYER, i);
                    return i;
                }
                else
                    mBoard[i] = curr;
            }
        }

        do
        {
            move = mRand.nextInt(getBOARD_SIZE());
        } while (mBoard[move] == HUMAN_PLAYER || mBoard[move] == ANDROID_PLAYER);

            setMove(ANDROID_PLAYER, move);
        return move;
    }

    public int checkForWinner()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 6; i += 3)
        {
            if (mBoard[i] == HUMAN_PLAYER &&
                mBoard[i+1] == HUMAN_PLAYER &&
                mBoard[i+2] == HUMAN_PLAYER)
                return 2;
            if (mBoard[i] == ANDROID_PLAYER &&
                mBoard[i+1] == ANDROID_PLAYER &&
                mBoard[i+2] == ANDROID_PLAYER)
                return 3;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
        {
            if (mBoard[i] == HUMAN_PLAYER &&
                mBoard[i+3] == HUMAN_PLAYER &&
                mBoard[i+6] == HUMAN_PLAYER)
                return 2;
            if (mBoard[i] == ANDROID_PLAYER &&
                mBoard[i+3] == ANDROID_PLAYER &&
                mBoard[i+6] == ANDROID_PLAYER)
                return 3;
        }

        if ((mBoard[0] == HUMAN_PLAYER &&
             mBoard[4] == HUMAN_PLAYER &&
             mBoard[8] == HUMAN_PLAYER) ||
             mBoard[2] == HUMAN_PLAYER &&
             mBoard[4] == HUMAN_PLAYER &&
             mBoard[6] == HUMAN_PLAYER)
             return 2;
        if ((mBoard[0] == ANDROID_PLAYER &&
             mBoard[4] == ANDROID_PLAYER &&
             mBoard[8] == ANDROID_PLAYER) ||
             mBoard[2] == ANDROID_PLAYER &&
             mBoard[4] == ANDROID_PLAYER &&
             mBoard[6] == ANDROID_PLAYER)
             return 3;

        for (int i = 0; i < getBOARD_SIZE(); i++)
        {
            if (mBoard[i] != HUMAN_PLAYER && mBoard[i] != ANDROID_PLAYER)
                return 0;
        }

        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Brute force? What options are there?

Comment: judging by this line : `move = mRand.nextInt(getBOARD_SIZE());` it appears to be entirely random unless there is a winning move - there is no strategy, such as capturing the middle square first.

Comment: Is there a specific section you are referring to?  There isn't much here that i would term an Algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

They're explicitly checking every possible winning move through looking at the cells.

I'd say that qualifies as a [brute force algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brute-force_search).

Comment: it doesn't, it only looks at the current move

Answer (score 0):

Its a depth limited search.   It looks ahead 1 move.

It checks if it can win. If it can't win it then checks that if there is a move the human can make that would let the human win, if there is a move that allows the human to win, then it takes that spot.

If it can't find a winning move or a win denying move it just chooses a random blank space

Answer (score 0):

It is making almost all possible checks.
It is a [Brute Force algorithm](http://www-igm.univ-mlv.fr/~lecroq/string/node3.html).

Comment: it doesn't, it only looks at the current move

Comment: I mean all possible moves that can be made afterwards.